# Need ideas to run multiple bash scripts in sequence with dependencies

Tags: bash

So it's not a problem per say, it's more of a situation that I'm currently in.

I have a bunch of scripts (Over 200) that need to run in sequence, some of them have dependencies on other scripts running and also completing succesfully

The current input parameters I can give

Each script writes a log file which has a clear XML output tag of either completed succesfully or critical fail

I need an idea of how I can write a global bash script that would run each script, and in case the script has dependencies it has to check the log file of the previous dependent script and validate that it's completed successfully.

I'm just having a hard time coming up with a fool-proof logic

Nothing tried yet, I'm just looking for ideas to build my logic/script on

Comment: I don't know if this will help, but generally when you need to manage dependencies at such a scale the way to do it is to build a [dependency graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_graph?useskin=vector) and run the scripts according to their [topological sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting?useskin=vector) order.

Comment: And there appears to be this standard utility that can do the heavy lifting for you: https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/tsort-invocation.html#tsort-invocation

Comment: Maybe use `make`?

Comment: Looks like this could be a job for `make`. Declare each log file as dependent on its script (in case the scripts change from time to time), model inter-scripts dependencies as inter-log-files dependencies. Make will stop if a script fails, no need to check the content of the log files. If the scripts don't exit with non-zero status when they fail, just add to the corresponding recipe a simple test about the log file content. The other benefits of using `make` is parallelism and that it never does twice the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Just brainstorming on how I would setup a master script...
I would probably put all scripts I need to run put in a (csv style) data file. On each line a script which will be executed one after the other. For scripts that are dependent on eachother I would have these on one line separated by a comma for example. E.g.

```
batch234.sh
batch240a.sh, batch240b.sh, batch240c.sh
batch115.sh
batch555a.sh, batch555b.sh
..etc...
```

The master script will then load this data file and process it line by line.
With each line I would check if there is a comma, if no then just execute this script. If yes, then I would loop on each element and execute them one by one but check each scripts logging before continuing (using a funcion which parses the xml-logging looking for the relevant keyword; assuming all scripts have the same output in their logging).

It sounds simple but once you try to implement something like this you will probably be struggling with all kind of issues you need to fix. For example; is the logging really generic enough to rely on one check? What do you need to do when you receive a return code higher than 0? Do we need to continue processing when it crashes (that would indicate we need to create a log to keep track what has already been run etc. and need an option to continue processing. What if a job hangs? Do we need to have it timeout (running them in the background so we could time it and kill it and maybe restart it)? What if the total processing takes too much time? (Risking overlap) How to prevent reentrant running? Are there also tasks that can run in parallel? You probably want to trap signals to do some housecleaning. Who to alert and how. Etc etc etc...

A fun scripting project, but I would probably implement this using a tool like Ansible instead of reinventing the wheel with my own masterscript.